# Java - Create XML Digital Signature using ECDSA (Elliptic Curve)

Tags: java, digital-signature, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, xml-dsig

We can create XML Digital Signature using RSA keys. But how do I use elliptic curve keys to sign xml files ? I get error messages such as -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyException: ECKeyValue not supported
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyValue$EC.<init>(DOMKeyValue.java:350)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(DOMKeyInfoFactory.java:71)
    at csr.ExtractEC.main(XMLSignatureECTest.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun/security/ec/ECParameters
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyValue$EC.getMethods(DOMKeyValue.java:367)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyValue$EC$1.run(DOMKeyValue.java:343)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyValue$EC$1.run(DOMKeyValue.java:339)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyValue$EC.<init>(DOMKeyValue.java:338)
    ... 2 more
```

I used below code to create SignatureMethod and KeyInfo -

```
String url = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256";
        SignatureMethod signatureMethod = factory.newSignatureMethod(url, null);
        SignedInfo signedInfo = factory.newSignedInfo(c14n, signatureMethod, Collections.singletonList(reference));

        PrivateKey privateKey = Utils.generatePrivateEC("e:\\certs\\ec\\ec.key.p8");
        Certificate certificate = Utils.generatePublic("e:\\certs\\ec\\ec.cer");
        KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = factory.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(certificate.getPublicKey());
        KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(keyValue));
```

JDK - Oracle JDK 8
Security Providers - BouncyCastle and Sun.

Comment: I do not understand why people just down votes any question, if it they are not interested. They creates problem for the community.

Comment: it is not just a downvote. There is no [MCVE] no informations about which JDK/JRE you use

Comment: Maybe [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8182580) helps

Comment: @Jens: Ugh, no workarounds given.

Comment: Really strange what's going on: it fails on Class.forName("sun.security.ec.ECParameters") but if you statically access the same class, or call Class.forName yourself it works, only to fail later in the library call. Are they messing with the class loaders?!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/mulderbaba/xmlsec/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/xml/security/test/signature/ECDSASignatureTest.java) test class? It seems you need exactly this...

Comment: Can you show how you're creating the `factory`? Also, where is this running? In JBoss, Tomcat, standalone, etc.?

Comment: @m4gic please post the link in answer so that i can select it as the correct answer and 50 points. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in [this](https://github.com/mulderbaba/xmlsec/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/xml/security/test/signature/ECDSASignatureTest.java) junit test someone is make an example for you.